# How can I resolve "CoreData: error: Serious application error" as a result of iCloud merge?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, icloud

Ok so I was in the final stages of testing of my app and now I have run into a problem that has stumped me.

The process is as follows:

1) Change via coredata to "Main table" which is linked to `myTableView` in the firstViewController

2) As part of the above code I am also deleting all prior objects and saving a string to "Sync Log Table". As a result this table should be left with one object, a string e.g. "Mon 20:33".
***Note: this is a newly implemented feature and I believe it to be the source of the problem, I want it as I am using it to populate a label on all devices to show the last synced data, in other words giving the user an easy check that all devices have the same information and are up to date***

3) Both changes are then saved by calling `[managedObjectContext save:&error];`

4) On a second device everything is working fine and I can make updates to 'Main Table" which show up on `myTableView` after calling the code to reload.

Note I had 3 rows showing in `myTableView` on the second device and the change which was made in step 1 to "Main Table" will not change the tableview on the second device due to the predicate which is filtering results.

**Then the problem starts**

5) The second device begins to receive the changes via iCloud and the delegate method:

```
- (void)mergeiCloudChanges:(NSNotification*)note forContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc {
NSLog(@"AppDelegate Merge icloud changes for context");
 //***Specifically the line below!!
[moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note]; 

NSNotification* refreshNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"RefreshAllViews" object:self  userInfo:[note userInfo]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:refreshNotification]; 
}
```

The line indicated above in the code kicks off the following methods in my firstViewController

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
NSLog(@"I'm inside the method Controller Will Change Context");
[self.myTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
NSLog(@"I'm inside the method Controller did Change Object");

UITableView *tableView = self.myTableView;

switch(type) {
        // And enters in this line here
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
   }
}
```

Then I get the error:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  
An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  
The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
```

After receiving this error, myTableView is no longer responsive, it won't update or respond to swipe to delete for instance.

Basically from my understanding, the objects which are getting merged from the "Sync Log table" are being inserted (when they shouldn't be) into the myTableView delegate methods which should only receive objects from "main table" thus throwing out the count and causing the error.

Any idea how to resolve this in my circumstances? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your tableview objects (ie, fetch controller, or NSArray, whatever) need to be updated before you call `insertRowsAt…` or `deleteRowsAt…` on the tableview itself. The tableview is telling you that the numbers don't add up for what it expects - if you are using a fetch controller, perhaps after you call `[moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note]`, you need to send a save message to the moc, or force a refresh for your table view's data objects.